# Exact value of probability related to random walk with negative drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

This is a sequel to [this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531900/upper-bound-on-hitting-probability-for-a-non-simple-one-dimensional-random-walk?noredirect=1).

Consider the random walk $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $(X_n)$ is an i.i.d. sequence of variables with distribution $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=-2)=\frac{1}{2}$, and let $E=\lbrace \exists n, S_n \geq 1 \rbrace$.

The accepted [answer to the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4531900/upper-bound-on-hitting-probability-for-a-non-simple-one-dimensional-random-walk/4532074#4532074) shows that $P(E)\leq \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2} \approx 0.62$. On the other hand, in the question it is also shown that $P(E)\geq 0.61$. It is therefore natural to ask :

Does $P(E) = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  There are two ways we can eventually gain a net $+1$ from the start: either

- the first step is $+1$, or
- the first step is $-2$, then we eventually gain a net $+1$ from there, then we eventually gain a net $+1$ from there, then we eventually gain a net $+1$ from there.

This gives $P(E) = \frac12 + \frac12P(E)^3$, which has three solutions.  We can discard $P(E) = \frac{-\sqrt5 - 1}{2}$ for being negative, and we can discard $P(E) = 1$ by the older question (or because it would violate the central limit theorem), leaving only $P(E) = \frac{\sqrt5 - 1}{2}$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I said “the first step is $-2$, then we **eventually** gain a **net** $+1$ from there”. Your example qualifies because it can be split up (uniquely) as $(-2, (-2, 1, 1, 1), (1), (1))$. That’s also why the equation is $P(E) = \frac12 + \frac12 P(E)^3$ and not $P(E) = \frac12 + \left(\frac12\right)^4$.

Comment: Let $F$ be the event where you gain a net $+1$ in some steps, then another net $+1$ in some steps, then a third $+1$ in some steps. You claim that $P(F)=P(E)^3$, but that is as yet unclear to me. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Starting at $k$, we can only eventually reach $k + 3$ by ($A$) eventually reaching $k + 1$ from $k$, then ($B$) eventually reaching $k + 2$ from $k + 1$, then ($C$) eventually reaching $k + 3$ from $k + 2$. This all happens with probability $P(A ∧ B ∧ C) = P(A)⋅P(B \mid A)⋅P(C \mid B) = P(E)⋅P(E)⋅P(E)$.

Comment: Looks ok to me now, I'll think about it for a few days before accepting this answer