# random walk with mean $>0$ what is the probablity that it goes to $0$ as starting point goes to infinity

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $X(i)$ be a random walk where starting at $i > 0$, at each step it increases by a positive integer $c > 1$ or goes down by $1$, with equal probability. Let $p_i$ be the probability that it goes to $0$. What I would like to know is how can I show that
$\lim_{i \to \infty} p_i = 0$?

I have been explained this holds because it is a random walk with mean $ > 0$, and I can understand it intuitively, but I am looking for a more rigorous explanation.
Thank you

Comment: I can't decide whether this is quite a duplicate, but I believe this provides a rigorous answer to your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4525584/the-down-cross-probability-of-a-general-random-walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some $i$,

\begin{align*}
p_i &= \mathbb{P}[\text{we arrive at $0$}] \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \mathbb{P}[\text{we arrive at $0$} \, | \, \text{we go forward a total of $j$ times}] \\
&\leq \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{j(c+1)+i}{j}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{j(c+1)+i} \\
&= \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{i} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{j(c+1)+i}{j}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{j(c+1)} \\
& \leq \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{i} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \bigg(\frac{c+1}{c}\bigg)^{i} \binom{j(c+1)}{j}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{j(c+1)} \\
& = \bigg(\frac{c+1}{2c}\bigg)^{i} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \binom{j(c+1)}{j}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{j(c+1)},
\end{align*}
which tends to $0$, as $i \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for this! Why is it $jc + i$ choose $j$?

Comment: I am sorry, I think now it is correct. If you go forward $j$ times, you need also to go back $i+jc$ times. So you need to make a total of $j+i+jc=j(c+1)+i$ moves. The question now is: How many possibilities are there to make $j$ moves forward and $i+jc$ moves backward and for this the answer is $j(c+1)+i$ choose $j$.

Comment: I am still not seeing this, as it does not seem to take into account that it may hit $0$ before all $j(c+1)+i$ steps have been taken. perhaps it should be $\leq$?

Comment: You are right, I edit my answer accordingly. Now the computation should work, yes?

Comment: I believe so, thanks!